# Tensorboard graph shows unmeaningful result no input size

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, visualization, tensorboard

I want to visualize a complex model with tensorboard graph. I run the code below to restore the graph from a ckpt.meta file. However, data flows are not display properly as I can't get useful information like input channels or image size. Components are not connected explicitly and inputs are represented as mul0-704 which looks like an intermediate var. I didn't run a training session and the original training is run with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession() which is something I do not have a firm grasp with currently. Why does this graph show a mess? I am a rookie with tensorboard and I want to refactor the code with pytorch. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. [disconnected graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tei5E.png), [mul0-704](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkJGc.png)

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.train.import_meta_graph('meta_file_dir')
export_dir = 'export_log_dir'
for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node:
   print(n)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(export_dir, sess.graph)
  writer.close()
```

Comment: Plus what is the best way to get the details of a complex model built with tf? How can we see connections between components?

Comment: Is your issue resolved? Else, May i know what are the details are you looking of complex model ? Please can you share complete reproduce the issue. Thanks!